# Show/hide upload button

Tags: angularjs

How can I show/hide an upload button based on if a file is selected or not.

I've tried this, but the button remains hidden:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Upload File</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" ng-model="formData.file">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div ng-show="formData.file.length">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default"
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `ngModel` on `input[type="file"]` is not natively supported by AngularJS.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: Not without knowing [which solution](https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=angularjs+file+upload) you'll use.

Comment: Okay, this is completely new to me. I would appreciate which solution to use. I am posting to a .aspx document.

Comment: Sadly, that's becoming an off-topic question. There isn't so many libraries for that, make a quick comparison and choose by yourself ;) .

Answer (score -1):

As Blackhole said in comments, this code can't work, ngModel on input[type="file"] is not natively supported by AngularJS.

For debug instance, add {{formData.file.length}} in your html code,  you'll see that the value is always null.